# How to use the Enter key as = button in calculator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to use the Enter key as `=` in the calculator and I inserted code that checks whether the user pressed the Enter key in the form key press, but the code in this `if` statement never evaluates to `true`:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return || e.KeyChar == (char)13 || e.KeyChar == '\r')
   btnequal_click(null,null);
```

The `btnequal_click(null,null)` call is supposed to fire when the user presses Enter.

What do I need to change to make this work?

Comment: And where do you have this code? What event handler?

Comment: He mentions "form key press" sp I assume that it is in the KeyPress EventHandler on the MainForm.

Comment: Can I suggest that you put a break statement on the "if". Then hit the  enter key and see what the value of e.KeyChar is

Answer (score 3):

You can simply set the [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of your form to `btnequal`. This should give you the wanted behaviour (`btnequal_click` get's called when hitting enter on that form).

As long as your form does not open using `ShowDialog`, it will not close after you hit "accept".

Answer (score 2):

Okay, well even though we don't have any clue where this code is, let me provide some guidance. Set the `KeyPreview` property of the `Form` to `true`. That will ensure that you get all key events.

Next, handle either the `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` events of the form and place the code in there.

I would recommend the `KeyUp` because `KeyDown` is replicated if the key is held down.

Finally all you need is this:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
   btnequal_click(null,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP said they were using the KeyPress event (or implied that) I will try to follow that. As a matter of fact, I recently coded a calculator that does the exact same thing. Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
        btnequal.PerformClick();
}
```

Note that I used the PerformClick function as I find it simpler. Also, as neoistheone mentioned, make sure you set your Form KeyPreview to true!